# Postgres injection tools

Tags: sql, security, postgresql

I am looking for tools that  I can use to audit the security of my database at the moment.  Does anyone have any resources on this?  I am running postgres, so that will take precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wapiti](http://wapiti.sourceforge.net/) is an open source tool for testing web application for many different types of vulnerabilities including sql injection.  It has signatures for testing for blind sql injection under Postgresql.

If you have some money to spend you can get [Sitewatch](https://sitewat.ch/en/About)($)  or NTOSpider($$$$$).

Answer (score 3):

[sqlmap](http://sqlmap.sourceforge.net/) is an open source SQL injection tool that works with PostgreSQL.  It runs on Python, though, so you would need to install a Python interpreter.

Comment: This is not for testing,  this is for exploitation.

Comment: Well I am trying to break my system to resolve vulnerabilities

Comment: @Woot4Moo No you already have access to your system,  you don't need to break in.  You need to test your software for vulnerabilities and then patch them.  Massive difference.  Sqlmap is for blackhats and penetration testers.

Comment: ahh thanks for the clarification.  Would it be worthwhile to learn the techniques from a security perspective?

Comment: @Woot4Moo yes it is defiantly worthwhile to know how sql injection is exploited.  There is no doubt you will be better and determining false positives and writing rock solid patches.